# Custom thread slots finishes faster then mainwindow slot

Tags: multithreading, qt

I need some help coz iv tried a lot but it didnt work and im lack off ideas now. Here is the thing. I have a QGraphicsScene with its scroll bars. When i pull the wheel or scroll bar it triggers scroll bar slot, which awakes processing threads. Each processing thread emits signal that it finished back to mainwindow. Mainwindow has slot that recives all this signals and when it recives all off them, it awakes thread that paint processed data. The thing is that the scroll bar slot offcours livs it own life and finishes befor other slots, that i mantioned. Thats why the scene moves faster then item appears on it and display efect if rather torn then smooth. Maybe some on have ideas what to do with it?

Iv tried to wait() my paint thread in scroll bar slot, tried to msleep() mainwindow, tried to loop scroll bar slot(was bad idea).

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way anyone will be able to help you unless you show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.